# load dynamically jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following script to load jquery in the head in case if is not already loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#nav li:has(ul)").hover(function(){
            $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
        }, function(){
            $(this).find("ul").hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
#nav {position: fixed; white-space:nowrap;}
#nav ul{ list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
#nav li { float:left; padding:0; margin:0;list-style: none;}
#nav li a { width:220px; display:block; text-align:center; color:#000; margin-right:5px; height:35px; line-height:35px; text-decoration:none; font-size:90%; border:1px solid #ccc;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: bold; }
#nav li a:hover { color:#f00; }
#nav ul ul { display:none; position:absolute; z-index:999; }
#nav li li { float:none; }
#nav li li a { background:#EBE7E6!important; text-align:left; height:auto; line-height:1; width:auto; padding:8px 20px 8px 22px; border:1px solid #D0D0D0; border-top:none; margin-right:0;width: 178px; }
* html li li { display:inline; } /* IE6 Bugfix... */
</style>
```

but it doesn't appear in the head.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the src attribute of a script tag?

Comment: What do you mean: "it doesn't appear in the head".  You won't see it in View/Source in the browser.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't appear in the head? It won't appear when you view the source of the page, but it should work if you inspect the document using the inspector.

Comment: just copy/pasted your code on jsFiddle.net and it works perfectly

Comment: firebug console shows ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: ok, is the problem that the script tag doesn't appear or that you are trying to use jQuery before it loads?

Comment: I'm going to upload my other parts of code

Comment: It does show up in `head` (not in View Source, though, but open the elements panel in dev tools). The script gets loaded asynchronously so it'll probably be after scripts on your page. If you have something that requires jQuery, that'll fail before this loads.

Comment: yepp there is there with inspect element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment '$ is not defined' this would indicate that your jQuery fallback is loading too late in the process. As SLaks pointed out, your fallback runs asynchronously.

Try inserting the script block in the head with a document.write(). This will force the browser to evaluate the script before any execution can continue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof (jQuery) === 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
</script>
```